# MySQL: How to filter results on columns through a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I need to know if the following can be resolved with a SQL query and how. I have done it with PHP in different ways but the memory skyrockets and the server takes a long time to return the results. :(

- I have a table called `'parts'` with many rows (but many).
- Each of the rows has the columns `part1`, `part2` and `part3`, all with different values.

Example:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| part1   | part2 | part3 | <-- Column Name
+---------+-------+-------+
| chamber | wheel | door  | <-- Value
+---------+-------+-------+
```

On the other hand I have a list of three values that come from an external source:

```
$list = ['mirror', 'seat', 'door'];
```

I need to select the rows whose columns contain **all** those values, regardless of the order. An example of a valid row would be:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| part1 | part2  | part3 |
+-------+--------+-------+
| door  | mirror | seat  |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

Sometimes the external list doesn't have 3 values, just 1 or 2:

```
$list = ['antenna'];
```

... Then the valid rows would be those that contain that value, for example:

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| part1  | part2  | part3   |
+--------+--------+---------+
| engine | mirror | antenna |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

- Additional info: In each row, the columns do not have repeated values,  so this feature can be ignored in the query.
- I need to know how to make a query for SELECT and another for COUNT.
- It is necessary that the result be resolved through a MySQL query, without using PHP for filtering.

Comment: _"I need to select the rows whose columns contain all those values, regardless of the order."_ - then you will have to create all possible combinations, and join them via OR. (Should become clear at this point, that this is a _bad_ data model to begin with.)

Comment: just 3 parts per row?

Comment: @CBroe, coincidentally, yesterday I tried to do it the way you suggest, but the query was growing a lot and there were still lines missing to complete all the possible combinations (approximately 50 values ​​x 3 columns). I support your clarification that you enclosed in parentheses ;)

Comment: @P.Salmon That's correct, 3 different parts chosen fromf a 50-55 part inventory. No part is repeated in the 3 columns of that row.

Comment: Not sure what the "50" you just mentioned is supposed to mean? You are looking for a combination of _three_ possible values only, are you not? So what is the relevance of that 50, how does that relate to your given example data now?

Comment: Normalize (unpivot) your data. Then you can use simple logical division.

Comment: Does the _order_ of the values in those three `partX` columns have any meaning? If not, then you could modify your data first, so that all records will contain this data in alphabetically sorted order. Then you would know upfront, that you don't need to look for `chamber | wheel | door` or `wheel | chamber | door` any more, and _only_ `chamber | door | wheel` _could_ even exist in the first place.

Comment: Will start a 250rep bounty in two days for this question (The system won't let me start it right now). If someone decides to write an answer that best solves the problem, I will gladly assign those reputation points to him.

Comment: How many rows is many?

Comment: @CBroe, there are an inventory of approximately 50 car spare parts. The client can only choose 3 of them through a form. On the other hand, the list sometimes has 3 parts available (taken from those 50 in the inventory), sometimes 2, and sometimes only 1. The filter would select all the rows that have all the parts in said list. That way we can give priority to those customers to ship the merchandise. :)

Comment: @P.Salmon +-2.5M

Comment: @CBroe It doesn't matter if the values ​​in the list are unordered. The important thing is to filter the rows that have all the spare parts in the list. :D

Comment: @Akina thanks for the suggestion. Will do the research how to do it that way. TY my friend.

Comment: _"It doesn't matter if the values ​​in the list are unordered"_ - if they _were_ ordered, then searching would become much easier, because then you would _not_ have to create all possible combinations of your search terms, _that_ was my point with that question ...

Comment: @CBroe I understand. You're right, the matter would be much easier if there was an order. I have repeatedly spoken to my bosses to achieve something in that direction and it is certainly an issue to be resolved in the future. Currently there are external agents that use the system in this way and it would be cumbersome to put a bit of order on the platform, especially because of the proximity of Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution.

```
CREATE TABLE parts
SELECT 'chamber' part1, 'wheel' part2, 'door' part3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'door', 'mirror', 'seat' UNION ALL
SELECT 'engine', 'mirror', 'antenna';
SELECT * FROM parts;
```

| part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chamber | wheel | door |
| door | mirror | seat |
| engine | mirror | antenna |

```
SELECT parts.*
FROM parts
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 'mirror' UNION
  SELECT 'seat' UNION
  SELECT 'door'
) criteria (value) 
GROUP BY parts.part1, parts.part2, parts.part3
HAVING SUM(criteria.value IN (parts.part1, parts.part2, parts.part3)) = COUNT(*)
```

| part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| door | mirror | seat |

```
SELECT parts.*
FROM parts
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 'mirror' UNION
  SELECT 'antenna'
) criteria (value) 
GROUP BY parts.part1, parts.part2, parts.part3
HAVING SUM(criteria.value IN (parts.part1, parts.part2, parts.part3)) = COUNT(*)
```

| part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| engine | mirror | antenna |

```
SELECT parts.*
FROM parts
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 'antenna'
) criteria (value) 
GROUP BY parts.part1, parts.part2, parts.part3
HAVING SUM(criteria.value IN (parts.part1, parts.part2, parts.part3)) = COUNT(*)
```

| part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| engine | mirror | antenna |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/suah1O5D)

If you don't want to convert your criteria array to subquery text (which must be concatenated into) then you may convert it to JSON array form, provide it to MySQL and parse to separate values in static subquery using JSON_TABLE().

Comment: Akina thank you for the answer. Will review & test your code right now and let you know. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, building on @CBroe's suggestion.  If you can sort the criteria before you insert them into the SQL statement, then this might work for you.

First normalise the parts list, then reassemble a string of matching parts in sorted order, separated by commas:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(part ORDER BY part) AS p
FROM (
    SELECT id, part1 AS part FROM parts
    UNION ALL SELECT id, part2 FROM parts
    UNION ALL SELECT id, part3 FROM parts
) partslist
WHERE part IN (?, ?, ?)
GROUP BY id
```

Finally wrap in a overall query that extracts the matching rows:

```
SELECT parts.*
FROM (
    SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(part ORDER BY part) AS p
    FROM (
        SELECT id, part1 AS part FROM parts
        UNION ALL SELECT id, part2 FROM parts
        UNION ALL SELECT id, part3 FROM parts
    ) partslist
    WHERE part IN (?, ?, ?)
    GROUP BY id
) partsjoined
INNER JOIN parts ON partsjoined.id = parts.id
WHERE partsjoined.p = CONCAT_WS(',', ?, ?, ?)
```

(reduce the number of ? parameters as appropriate)

Again, this assumes you're able to sort the criteria parameters before binding them to the statement.

Comment: `CONCAT_WS(',', ?, ?, ?)` must be sorted according to the collation which is applied in `GROUP_CONCAT()`. If the values contains national symbols then this may be problematic..

Comment: Fair point.  Come to think about it, doing this string-wise is probably also not very performant.  @Akina's solution is neater